# Flexbox not shrinking to width of upper display:block container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container, a sidebar, that contains the div in the picture. The sidebar has display: block and there is a flexbox div at the bottom. The sidebar changes width based on device width, but the inner flexbox doesn't. The overflow continues to show over the edge instead of shrinking the inside div and making the p elements go to ellipsis. This has been bothering me for days since whenever I open devconsole this happens.

```css
div#sidebar-pdm {
                background-color: var(--thlv-el-color);
                position: relative;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 20%;
            }

            div#myinfo {
                text-align: left;
                color: var(--text-color);
                max-width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                background-color: var(--tlv-el-color);
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0px;
                height: 10%;
                align-items: center;
            }

            div#myinfo p {
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }

            div#myinfo img {
                height: 80%;
                vertical-align: middle;
                padding: 5%;
                border-radius: 35%;
            }

            div#myinfo div {
                flex:0 1000;
            }
```

```html
<div id="myinfo">
                    <img src="{{ user['pfp_url'] }}" onclick="update_status()">
                    <div>
                        <p style="margin:0;">{{ user['username'] }}</p>
                        <p style="margin:0; color: var(--disc-color);">#{{ user['discriminator'] }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="flex:1; text-align:center;">
                        <a href='/' style="color: var(--text-color); text-decoration:none;"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: flexbox after rendering]